# How to load and display external multipolygon geoJSON file in ngx-leaflet angular app

Tags: angular, leaflet, geojson, ngx-leaflet

I am using the template from the [ngx-leaflet tutorial](https://www.asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-angular-cli/) for this example. I am a total beginner to Angular and just barely know leaflet.js, for reference.

I have a large multipolygon geoJSON file that I want to display on a map and eventually add interactivity to. I've saved the file in the `assets` directory as `china_adm1.geojson`.

`app.component.html` looks like:

```
<div class="map"
     leaflet
     [leafletOptions]="options"
     [leafletLayers]="china"
     [leafletLayersControl]="layersControl"
>
</div>
```

and `app.component.ts` looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { geoJSON, latLng, tileLayer } from 'leaflet';
import { adm1 } from '../assets/china_adm1';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  china = geoJSON(adm1);

  // Define our base layers so we can reference them multiple times
  googleMaps = tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
    detectRetina: true
  });

  googleHybrid = tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
    maxZoom: 20,
    subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3'],
    detectRetina: true
  });

  options = {
    layers: [ this.googleMaps ],
    zoom: 3, 
    center: latLng(0, 0)
  };

  layersControl = {
    baseLayers: {
      "Google": this.googleMaps,
      "Hybrid": this.googleHybrid
    },
    overlays: {
      "China Polygon": this.china
    }
  };
}
```

When I run the app with the above code, the Google basemap displays nicely, but the layersControl panel is absent. When I remove the entire `overlays` portion of the layersControl code, the control panel shows up as expected. There's something I'm missing about loading/displaying the China regions geoJSON. Note that in `import { adm1 } from '../assets/china_adm1`, I've arbitrarily defined `adm1`, so maybe that's the issue. I've also tried including `this.china` in the layers options bside `this.googleMaps`.

In leaflet.js, it's as simple as `L.geoJson(adm1).addTo(map);` where I've defined `adm1` with

```
var adm1 = {"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "china_adm1", ...}
```

in the geojson file. I'm not sure how to properly define and reference the geojson file in ngx-leaflet.

Comment: It appears that you have to use HTTPclient per [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49089788/getting-geojson-data-to-leaflet-map-using-ngx-leaflet-httpclient-and-angular2)

Comment: Leaving this marked unanswered because I'm not sure that HTTPClient is the best/only way to load a geojson into an ngx-leaflet app.

Comment: I'd suggest you debug and inspect the objects being placed into the overlays object when you manually define a json object vs when you use the file-loader. I wouldn't be surprised if it's some issue like it's a string and not a parsed JSON object or something. Or, if there's some difference in the JSON structure. Are there any console errors? Did you debug to see what's getting loaded?