# Leaflet - import Geojson - Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, geojson, ngx-leaflet

i try to import GeoJson file to leaflet in angular's app 6.

With this solution my geojson is drawn in leafletmap but i have this error and i can't build my app. Someone know one solution ?

> ERROR TS2345 Argument of type '{"type": string;"features":({"type":
>   string; "geometry": { "type: string : "coordinates": num...' is not
>   assignable parameter of type GeoJsonObject

Model.ts

```
export const Pdl = [ 'my geojson' ];
```

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alanent/france-geojson/master/regions/pays-de-la-loire/departements-pays-de-la-loire.geojson

Component.ts

```
import { LeafletModule } from '@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import {Pdl} from "../models/pdl.model"; 

@Component({
   selector: 'app-geo',
   templateUrl: './geo.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./geo.component.scss']
})
export class GeoComponent implements OnInit { 

    ngOnInit() {    
       var mapboxAccessToken = "...";

       const myfrugalmap = L.map('frugalmap').setView([47.482019, -1], 7);

       L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=' + mapboxAccessToken, {
          id: 'mapbox.light',
          attribution: 'SOS'
       }).addTo(myfrugalmap);

       L.geoJSON(Pdl).addTo(myfrugalmap);
    }
}
```

Maybe, i can hide the error ? what is the way ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do it the 'angular way' since you are using ngx-leaflet

Importing a json via import is a nightmare in my personal opinion so what I would do would be to fetch it using a get request when the map is loaded and then get a reference to the map object and add the geojson.

template:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import * as L from 'leaflet';
..
map: L.Map;
json;
options = {
    layers: [
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { 
            maxZoom: 18, attribution: '...'
        })
    ],
    zoom: 7,
    center: L.latLng(47.482019, -1)
};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

onMapReady(map: L.Map) {
    this.http.get('assets/departements.json').subscribe((json: any) => {
        console.log(json);
        this.json = json;
        L.geoJSON(this.json).addTo(map);
    });
}
```

template

```
<div leaflet style="height: 800px"
    [leafletOptions]="options"
    (leafletMapReady)="onMapReady($event)">
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/x3l39kqvlp)

Comment: I try this but now i have no error but no geojson on my map. Could you put on stackblitz please ?

Comment: I have attached a link to a github repo.

Comment: thank you very muck, i didn' worked with ngx-leaflet just leaflet, so i will go to install ngx leaflet

Comment: No problem. And be careful. Do not publish your mapboxAccessToken because other people can use it. I edited your question and removed it.

Comment: I've been looking for a simple solution on how to do this and this is it...you wouldn't believe how many stupidly complicated ways I have seen to do this!